# MySQL double averaging with double grouping

Tags: mysql

I have the following data in a MySQL table called test

[image]

I run the following SQL query

```
SELECT user_id, 
       group_id, 
       sum(value) as total_present, 
       avg(value)*100 as attendance_percentage 
FROM test t 
WHERE t.session_date BETWEEN '2017-10-01' AND '2017-10-15'
GROUP BY user_id
```

This gives me percentages for each user_id like this:

[image]

If you look at the output example above, user_id 1 and 2 are in the same group_id. So is there a way for me to further group my query to then take an average of the same group_id's. So for the example above, the group_id 3 percentage should be 70.83335

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Note that group_id is a random value in the qeury you used.. doesn't look like user_id is a PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE KEY in the table.. So using `SELECT user_id, group_id ....GROUP BY user_id` is not a valid ANSI GROUP BY... read https://www.psce.com/en/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/

Comment: @RaymondNijland the PK  is id, one user appear several times but in different date, the query is ok.

Comment: The query is only "ok" because the topic starter doesn't have sql-mode only_full_group_by enabled @JuanCarlosOropeza

Comment: @RaymondNijland That isnt what you say. You are talking about PK and Unique key And if you are used mysql before now that is the default setting.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Why isnt "SELECT user_id, group_id ....GROUP BY user_id" valid if the user_id and group_id are not PK or UK? These two fields cannot be PK or UK because a user_id can have multiple entries for multiple dates same goes with the group_id. I have a seperate field called id which is the first field and that is unique and is primary key.

Answer (score 1):

Khalid answer is OK. But I think you should consider the problem you are averaging different things with different magnitude. user_id = 2 has more values than user_id = 1 so his percentage should weight more.

For example if user_id = 3 only went once with 100% attendance that will distort the avg.

You should do:

```
 SELECT group_id, avg(value)
 FROM yourTable
 GROUP BY group_id
```

In this case the `AVG()` is 71.42 instead of 70.83

Comment: Agreed, if you need both then do two queries.  One grouped by user and one grouped by group

Answer (score 0):

You can by applying further aggregation on your query

```
SELECT t.group_id, avg(t.attendance_percentage) as t.group_attendance_percentage 
FROM(
    SELECT user_id, group_id, sum(value) as total_present, avg(value)*100 as attendance_percentage 
    FROM test t 
    WHERE t.session_date BETWEEN '2017-10-01' AND '2017-10-15'
    GROUP BY user_id
) t
GROUP BY t.group_id
```